# JavaScript SpeechSynthesisUtterance speak out numbers properly

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

I use the SpeechSynthesisUtterance with JavaScript and HTML. I want to speak out numbers properly, so instead of it reading five three seven seven nine, like fivtythreethousand sevenhundered, and seventy nine. Is that possible? I am getting the number from a localStorage.
I am using this code:

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("The number is " + localStorage.getItem("mynumber"));
msg.lang = 'en-US';
msg.rate = 4;
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

`

Comment: I don't know what's returned from `localStorage.getItem("mynumber")`, but I just tried with "The number is 53779" and it was uttered properly. What's the browser and OS you're testing it in?

Comment: Windows 10, Chrome 70.0. 76301129 is returned.

Comment: Indeed, it kind of falls back to uttering single digits when the number has more than 6 digits. I can't find any mention of why it works like this elsewhere, but it worked when I passed "The number is 76301129" as "The number is 76,301,129".

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/text mentions that you can use SSML  for that. So you could use `<say-as interpret-as="characters">12</say-as>` for example. I could not get SpeechSynthesis working at all for a demo though, so I'm just commenting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How the number is pronounced depends on the browser and the voice selected from that browser. When I try in Chrome the default voice says "fiftythree seventyseven nine", however if I give the number a thousands separator (i.e. change it from 53779 to 53,779) all voices say "fiftythree thousand seven hundred and seventynine."

Therefore try adding ".toLocaleString('en')" which adds the thousand separator:

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("The number is " + localStorage.getItem("mynumber").toLocaleString('en'));
```